# Setting metric/imperial as default units

Tags: units, scale

I know you can set the units and scale of a scene to metric/imperial. 
Since I recently got a 3D printer and now need to model after exact measurements, is there a way to set the default units to metric/imperial so I don't have to do this ever time I begin a new model?

Comment: Set the units to the system that you want to use, then press Ctrl+U to save the startup file. New projects will use the saved settings.

Comment: Thanks, looks like didn't search the right thing. Maybe this still will help people with a similar question.